# Derive type for extension's static func

Tags: swift, generics, swift-extensions

I want to make a method to return all NSManagedObject of a specific class as an extension:

```
extension NSManagedObject {
   static func getAll() -> [NSManagedObject]? {
       // code
   }
}
```

How can I specify the exact type of returned objects? So, for class Animal, I could infer type in the next example:

```
let animals = Animal.getAll() // I want to animals already be [Animal]?, not [NSManagedObject]?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you going to fetch all objects the same way? If so, you can try this way:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

protocol AllGettable {
    associatedtype GetObjectType
    static func getAll() -> [GetObjectType]?
}

extension AllGettable {
    static func getAll() -> [Self]? {
        return []/* fetch your objects */ as? [Self]
    }
}

class Animal: NSManagedObject, AllGettable {}

let animals = Animal.getAll()
```